# Routing table hits?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, routing, routes

With iptables -L -n -v, you can get the number of times each firewall rule has been applied, which is very useful in debugging.  I'd like to know if there's a similar way to find out how many times a network route has been used.  I'm mostly asking about Linux and Windows solutions, but any platforms' solutions to this would be interesting.

Comment: Added `Windows` to tags, for Windows guru to notice the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
route -neeC
```

and look at the "Use" column. `man route` says this is the count of lookups for the route.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful.  I'm not entirely sure that a lookup against a route is the same thing as a final decision to use that route AFTER conducting a lookup.  Is this safe to assume?

Comment: Fwiw, this 2009 answer will not work anymore (empty result) on linux >= 3.6 (~2012): [ipv4: Delete routing cache](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=89aef8921bfbac22f00e04f8450f6e447db13e42)

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD:

```
netstat -rn
```

Linux:

```
netstat -rneC
```

Windows:
I think something can be done via `netsh`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get this information directly, but it would be relatively straightforward with a set of empty rules in iptables that match up with the rules in the routing table.