# Linux - find hits of default route

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking, route

Sort of the similar question as this - [Routing table hits?](https://serverfault.com/questions/78060/routing-table-hits) - except that I don't use iptables and  looking for normal routing hits in kernel routing table.

But my usecase is finding how many packets are being forwarded via the default route in my firewall, in order to make sure it's useless before I delete it. The responses to the mentioned question include inspecting the cache, but is it possible that some packets will be forwarded without hitting the cache?

In addition, after inspecting the cache the command recommended (`route -neeC`) just terminates and I'd like to inspect default route "lookup hits" for a long period (~24 hours). Any recommendations on how to do that?

Cheers.

Comment: What about a tcpdump pcap file and filter?

Comment: @Lenniey , pcap doesn't help me as it doesn't show the route used. Think about a scenario where I have a default gateway pointing at 1.1.1.1, but also another 10 routes pointing at 1.1.1.1. A capture will show me many packets going there but not the route used to determine the next hop.

Comment: Yeah, filter the target IP to your gateway and the source IP != your IP. If you don't use NAT or anything, this should show you packets not originating from your machine, but targeting your gateway.

Comment: But this is a firewall, it functions as a router. There's no traffic originating from my machine, and traffic targeting the gateway could be sourced in addresses that are using the default route and some addresses that are using specific routes.

Comment: Why does it matter if you delete the default gateway, if "10 routes are pointing to 1.1.1.1"?

Comment: Because a lot of traffic is going there because of the default route... I have some specific routes as well but I suspect some traffic is still using the default .

Comment: No particular reason, except that our security team really like CheckPoint and CheckPoint really dislike running stuff on their firewalls. How would nftables help? Can you see route hits in nftables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linux routing cache for IPv4 has been removed in [Linux 3.6](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=89aef8921bfbac22f00e04f8450f6e447db13e42) (leaving only the use of an optimized [LPC-trie](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-ipv4-route-lookup-linux#lookup-with-a-level-compressed-trie)). There's thus no way with a Linux system with an OS from after 2012 to get routing *cache* statistics.

---

An easy way to *tag* the usage of the default route is to place a *realm* value on this route. A packet matching this route (rather than a more specific route using the same gateway) will be identified as being with the given realm value. So if the default route was 192.0.2.1 via *eth0*, the route would be set for example like this:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 proto static realm 10
```

Or you could change a previous default route (without realm) by replacing `add` with `change`, without disruption.

This realm tag can then be reused at least in two other network subsystems: [`tc filter ... route`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-route.8) or nftables' [`nft ... meta rtclassid`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#META_EXPRESSIONS).

---

### [Traffic Control](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/intro.html)

`tc` is quite crude and usually working at the interface level. The easiest way to attach a filter is to use the [`prio`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-prio.8) qdisc, the simplest classful qdisc. Its specific priority properties won't be actually used. So following on the previous example:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
```

Now add the filter with an empty action (and with a *pref* order and a *continue* control to allow additional similar filters if needed), just to have statistics on it:

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 route to 10 action continue
```

Now every ip packet matching route realm 10, will be shown in statistics by using `tc -s filter show dev eth0`. Example:

```
# tc -s filter show dev eth0
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 route chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 route chain 0 fh 0xffff000a to 10 
    action order 1: gact action continue
     random type none pass val 0
     index 1 ref 1 bind 1 installed 48 sec used 4 sec
    Action statistics:
    Sent 12230 bytes 79 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
    backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

Note: both forwarded *and* locally originated packets are matching, which could be a problem for measurements.

---

### [nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page)

*nftables* here won't be used to do any kind of firewalling, but just to increment some counters.

*nftables* installs only requested netfilter's hooks, rather than all available, thus usually having a lesser footprint than *iptables*. Here we just need a rule matching the realm - that's the role of the *rtclassid* expression -  with a counter on it. If it's for locally originated packets, then just use the *output* hook. The forward hook will match only forwarded packets.

```
nft add table ip mystats
nft add chain ip mystats forward '{ type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip mystats forward meta rtclassid 10 counter
```

Which would give for example later:

```
# nft list ruleset
table ip stats {
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        meta rtclassid 10 counter packets 1453 bytes 118264
    }
}
```

Zeroing the value is possible only if storing it in a named object, the ruleset would be instead (to load with `nft -f file`):

```
table ip mystats {
    counter defaultroutecount { }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        meta rtclassid 10 counter name "defaultroutecount"
    }
}
```

Then `nft list counters` or `nft reset counters` will display (or display and reset) its content.

Comment: Thank you so much! What an amazing answer. Great news!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
iptables -vL
```

or for forwarding:

```
iptables -t nat -vL
```

to see the number of packets per matching rule.

Comment: But I don't have iptables enabled and not using any rules...

Comment: Ah.. ok, in that case try having a look into /proc/net/fib_triestat (maybe save the state at time X and compare with the state at time X + 24h). You can find more info here: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-ipv4-route-lookup-linux